# How do I represent the set of all finite bit strings?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science, bit-strings

At first I thought I could just represent them with the set of natural numbers, because each bit string represents some natural number. However doing this would mean the strings '010' and '00010' are the same, which they are not.

Comment: What do you mean by represent? Do you mean, find some well-known or understandably constructed set that is bijective with the set of finite-length binary strings?

Comment: If so, how does $2^\omega$ work for you?

Comment: Perhaps an extension to a subset of $\Bbb Q$, something like $\frac n{(n+1)^k}$ for a number $n$ with $k$ leading zeroes?

Comment: A notation for it is $\{0,1\}^*,$ where the star means Klein star. Which is $$\bigcup _{i = 0}^{\infty}\{0,1\}^i,$$ and $\{0,1\}^i$ are i ordered tuples of elements from $\{0,1\}$

Comment: How about making each 0 in a string 1 and each 1 in a string 2 and then interpreting the string as a list of exponents of primes in the unique factorisation of some number, e.g. $010$ goes to $121$ and so $2^1\times3^2\times5^1 = 90$ or $00010$ goes to $11121$ and thus $2^1\times3^1\times5^1\times7^2\times11^1$...

Comment: I really like the $2^\omega$ and the prime number representation (its kinda like [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel_numbering)), but I think the [Kleene Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) is probably the standard notation for this set.

Comment: @IskyMathews "$2^\omega$" denotes the set of *infinite* binary strings.

Comment: @Noah Schweber: Thank you! That was a silly typo.

Comment: @OzanerHansha If you're looking for a notation for naming this set, "$2^{<\omega}$" is also used (it's the standard in mathematical logic, for example).

Comment: I see. I guess $\{0,1\}^+$ ($\{0,1\}^*$ includes the empty set) is more computer science-y and $2^{<\omega}$ is more set theory-y. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one easy way to biject the finite binary strings to the natural numbers (let's say we're thinking of the natural numbers as **not** including zero):

- Step $1$: put a "$1$" on the left.
- Step $2$: view the resulting string as a number in binary as usual.

E.g. "$010$" turns into "$1010$," which is ten. The empty string meanwhile turns into the string $1$, which then turns into the number one.

---

If we want to get $0$ in the mix too, we can just add "Step $3$: subtract $1$" to the above.